# Swift: Make camera follow player as he jumps

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a platform game and I want to make the camera (smoothly, if possible) follow the player, as he jumps. But I don't want it to happen if the player is in the lower position of the game.

I already have a var called `sceneLower`, which is the lower position of the scene, and I have this code (which is not complete):

```
var cameraOk = false;
var cameraMoving = false
func moveCamera(position: CGFloat = 0, toPlayer: Bool = false) {
    if !self.cameraOk {
        cameraMoving = true
        let action = SKAction.moveToY((toPlayer ? Player.position.y + 100 : position), duration: 0.6)
        //SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: by), duration: 0.1)
        self.cam.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, SKAction.runBlock({ 
            self.cameraOk = true
            self.cameraMoving = false
        })]))
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    if (Player.position.y > sceneLower + self.frame.height / 2) {
        if !cameraOk {
            moveCamera(toPlayer: true)
        }
        if (!cameraMoving) {
            self.cam.position.y = Player.position.y + 100
            cameraOk = true
        }
    } else {
        if (!cameraMoving) {
            moveCamera(cameraInitPosition)
        }
    }
```

I want the camera to follow the player only if he is in a mid-high position of the scene, and if he comes back to the lower position, I want the camera to follow him back. I don't know how to make that happen.

Please, comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Maybe consider adding variables to your player isInTheAir that you would set to true when jumping and to false when lands again. Then simply in your update() call do if player.isInTheAir self.cam.position = player.position. I would try to avoid checking the y-coordinates. I have some bad experiences from that, doesn't feel controlled and universally working across devices, scenes, etc.

Comment: But I want the camera to follow the player when he is in a mid-high position, not only when he jumps.
I have the same feel about you about the universally devices, but I didn't think any way better to do this

Comment: So what is your current code doing and what is still missing / not working?

Comment: The camera doesn't move back when the player is in the lower-mid position and I don't know if I'm doing this the best way there is. Also, I couldn't find any tutorial for cameras in platform games like this on the internet, which kinda surprises me

Comment: if (!cameraMoving) {
          moveCamera(cameraInitPosition)
 } what if you change this to if (cam.position != cameraInitPosition) moveCamera(cameraInitPosition)

Comment: Welp, that will kinda do the trick for now, with some other minor changes that I made. I think I can figure out what to do now, thanks!

Comment: Added an answer for future generations and to comply with site format.

Comment: Is the goal only to move the camera on the Y axis?

Comment: Yep, only in the y axis

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!cameraMoving) {
    moveCamera(cameraInitPosition)
}
```

What if you change this to:

```
if (cam.position != cameraInitPosition) {
     moveCamera(cameraInitPosition)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudocode for this problem.

```
if playerInJumpingState {
camera.position += player.deltaPosition
}
```

Here, playerInJumpingState is true only when player is in jumping animation state.

Then, what you do is add the difference in player's position in between the frame ( previous frame and current frame) i.e. deltaPosition to the camera's position. This way, the camera will follow the player when he/she is jumping.

**Note: Do not forget to set playerInJumpingState to false when he has landed back in ground.**

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari